# How to skip next schedule of DAG if previous run not yet finished by the time of next schedule?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a case to skip an entire run of a DAG if by the time of upcoming schedule the previous one has not yet finished. Is there a way to do this?

Imagine a DAG needs to run every hour and a scheduled run on 9AM not yet finish by the time it is 10AM, in my case I would like to skip the 10AM run entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `max_active_runs=1` & `catchup=False` in your DAG constructor

```
dag = DAG(
    ...,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will skip it and will not wait until the first finish to start the second one? The documentation is not really clear on this.

Comment: @angelcervera That is what catchup all about. If you find case where you see defrent behavior feel free to open GitHub discussion in the project with example and we can take it further. Let me note that we always improve documentation and code so you can also help us by open PRs to the project to improve it for others

Comment: I was able to confirm this behavior with a simple test case dag in Airflow 2.3

Comment: I feel like catchup refers to unscheduled tasks between start_date and current time when the DAG is first turned on. If the next run has already been scheduled catchup has no effect.